# QGIS 3 can not set a relative path to Form UI file

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I have created a custom form ui file, and everything is working fine if I pass the absolute path of my ui file to QGIS.

But I need to use the relative path, because I need to package the project file and ui file together and give it to end users.

The .ui file is located beside the project .qgs file, and I tried the relative path as in the attached image, but the QGIS doesn't load my custom form.
I'm using QGIS 3.10.0 on a linux machine.
[image]